# Firefox source code for Android

Tags: android, firefox

I have recently seen the release of [Firefox for Android](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/mobile/features/). It appears that firefox has several awesome features and performance improvements. I want to know if the source code for the Android platform has been released and if so where can I get the latest source code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's hosted in a mercurial repository here:

- http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/
- https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev (Git mirror)

Hit the wiki pages here for instructions on building and usage:

- https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/contributor/geckoview-quick-start.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Git

Comment: Bottom link is now broken.

Comment: it's now hosted on github https://github.com/mozilla-mobile

Answer (score 1):

The link to the source code archive. It has sources for desktop and mobile Firefox.

Link : http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/35.0/source/firefox-35.0.source.tar.bz2

Unpack => mobile/android

Comment: Link is now broken.

`wget ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/35.0/source/firefox-35.0.source.tar.bz2`
--2020-08-29 10:44:49--  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/35.0/source/firefox-35.0.source.tar.bz2
           => ‘firefox-35.0.source.tar.bz2’
Resolving ftp.mozilla.org (ftp.mozilla.org)... 13.225.146.57, 13.225.146.55, 13.225.146.42, ...
Connecting to ftp.mozilla.org (ftp.mozilla.org)|13.225.146.57|:21... failed: Connection timed out.`

Comment: Changed link to `http`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Now how about shortening the link to just:  Link : http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases , as version 35 is quite old now.

Comment: @Ellipticalview In the meantime a trailing slash is required to access direcories, so the url is https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/